# A condition for Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) $ with   $-\Delta(u) -c  (x^{2}+y^{2})u  \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ where  $c>0$.

Is true $-\Delta u \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $c<0$?

Comment: if $c<0$ i think is true, i suppose $c>0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a smooth, non-negative function supported on the interval $[1,2]$.

Consider the function in polar coordinates

$$ u_{\rho,\sigma}(r,\theta) = v( r - \rho) \sin( \sigma \theta) $$

A direct computation gives

$$ \triangle u_{\rho,\sigma} = \sin(\sigma\theta) \cdot \left[ v''(r - \rho) + \frac{1}{r} v'(r - \rho) - \frac{\sigma^2}{r^2} v(r-\rho) \right] $$

while

$$ \triangle u_{\rho,\sigma} + r^2 u_{\rho,\sigma} = \sin(\sigma\theta) \cdot \left[  v''(r - \rho) +  \frac{1}{r} v'(r - \rho) + \frac{r^4 - \sigma^2}{r^2} v(r-\rho) \right] $$

Observe that $r^4 - \sigma^2 = (r^2 - \sigma)(r^2 + \sigma)$.

Now let $\sigma$ be some large integer. And take $\rho = \sqrt{\sigma} - 1$. Then when $r - \rho \in [1,2]$ we have $r^2 - \sigma \in [0,2\sqrt{\sigma} + 1]$. So asymptotically we have that as $\sigma \to\infty$
$$ \| \triangle u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma}\|_2 \approx \sigma^{5/4} $$
while
$$ \| \triangle u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma} + r^2 u_{\sqrt{\sigma}-1,\sigma} \|_2 \approx \sigma^{3/4} $$

---

So now take

$$ u = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k^{-3} u_{k, (k+1)^2} $$

One easily checks that $u\in L^2$, $\triangle u + r^2 u \in L^2$, but $\triangle u\not\in L^2$.

Comment: I think in $\| \triangle u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma}\|_2 \approx \sigma^{5/4}$ we must have $\| \triangle u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma}\|_2 \approx \sigma^{3/4}$?

Comment: @Kacdima Why? The two are constructed to differ (the $L^2$ norms of $\triangle u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma}$ and $(\triangle + r^2) u_{\sqrt{\sigma} - 1, \sigma}$ that is).